# Projecting Reference Lines in a SmoothHistogram3d Surface

Tags: graphics3d

What is the best way to draw a path (red color, dashed) along the surface of the smoothHistogram3D. Assume the paths desired to be the X=0 and Y=0 Axes.

```
data = {{0.798333, 1.21167}, {-0.415, 0.915}, {-0.675, 0.715}, {0.785, 
0.675}, {-0.55, 0.645}, {-0.125, 0.57}, {0.15, 0.27}, {-0.3, 
0.115}, {0.925, -0.685}, {0.748333, 1.27167}, {-0.465,
0.975}, {-0.725, 0.775}, {0.735, 0.735}, {-0.6, 0.705}, {-0.175, 
0.63}, {0.1, 0.33}, {-0.35, 0.175}, {0.875, -0.625}, {0.628333, 
1.18167}, {-0.585, 0.885}, {-0.845, 0.685}, {0.615, 0.645}, {-0.72,  
0.615}, {-0.295, 0.54}, {-0.02, 0.24}, {-0.47, 
0.085}, {0.755, -0.715}, {0.718333, 1.23167}, {-0.495, 
0.935}, {-0.755, 0.735}, {0.705, 0.695}, {-0.63, 0.665}, {-0.205,
0.59}, {0.07, 0.29}, {-0.38, 0.135}, {0.845, -0.665}, {0.738333, 
1.23167}, {-0.475, 0.935}, {-0.735, 0.735}, {0.725, 0.695}, {-0.61, 
0.665}, {-0.185, 0.59}, {0.09, 0.29}, {-0.36, 
0.135}, {0.865, -0.665}, {1.07833, 1.43167}, {-0.135, 
1.135}, {-0.395, 0.935}, {1.065, 0.895}, {-0.27, 0.865}, {0.155, 
0.79}, {0.43, 0.49}, {-0.02, 0.335}, {1.205, -0.465}};
SmoothHistogram3D[data]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `Mesh`.

```
plot = SmoothHistogram3D[data];
path = SmoothHistogram3D[data,
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[{plot, path}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Like that?

```
SmoothHistogram3D[data, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> 1, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]